# Disabling buttons after Tic Tac Toe game has ended

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks to the help of people here I managed to disable clicking on the divs and overwriting them when they've already been selected by using `$(".pos").addClass('already-played');` and this in the CSS:

`.already-played {
  pointer-events: none;
}`

I tried adding this `$(".pos").addClass('already-played');` to a bunch of functions to try to disable the board completely once there has been a win or a draw, but it hasn't worked. For example, here:

```
            //if a row or column win occurs, return 1
            if (rowComplete || colComplete) {
                return value ? 1 : 0;
                $(".pos").addClass('already-played');
            }
        }

        //if a diagonal win occurs, return 1
        if (diagComplete1 || diagComplete2) {
            return value ? 1 : 0;
            $(".pos").addClass('already-played');
        }
    }

    //draw
    if (allNotNull) {
        return -1;
        $(".pos").addClass('already-played');
    }
```

I also tried this function:

```
function disableBoard() {
    if ($("#status").text() != "") {
         $(".pos").addClass('already-played');
    }
}
```

This either does nothing, or disables clicks after the first go. [Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1apoya1/10/). Any ideas?

Comment: you need to add it before your returns (the code after the return won't get hit as you have returned out of the function)

Comment: Good point! Though that didn't fix it, now it disables the clicks after the first move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace with this

```
function updateMove() {
    updateButtons();
    var winner = getWinner(board);
        if(winner==1 || winner==0 || winner==-1)
           $(".pos").addClass("already-played")
        $("#status").text(winner == 1 ? "Your computer won!" : winner == 0 ? "You won!" : winner == -1 ? "It's a draw!" : "");
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!